# load remote data from json

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am developing a hybrid live streaming app in ionic4. I have to load remote data from json to get url of my channel for live streaming. I am using http method to get data from json but I am getting error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

So that's why I am using CORS policy of IONIC to avoid this error. But now I am facing error of

```
Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
[ng]  Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
[ng]    Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type '{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
[ng]    Index signature is missing in type 'Headers'.
```

I am using http method to get data from json but i am getting error of "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."
So that's why I am using CORS policy of IONIC to avoid this error.

## Function to load data:

### reddit-data.Service.ts

```
getRemoteData() {
  const headerDict = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
  }
  const requestOptions = {
    headers: new Headers(headerDict),
  };
  this.http.get("url", requestOptions).subscribe((res) => {
    //console.log(data);
    err => {
      console.log(err)
    }
  });
}
```

#### homepage.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.redditService.getRemoteData();
}
```

#### I am getting error of header:

```
[ng] ERROR in src/app/services/reddit-data.service.ts(56,75): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ headers: Headers; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.
[ng]  Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
[ng]    Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
[ng]    Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type '{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
[ng]    Index signature is missing in type 'Headers'.
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2B6FE.png)

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` is a **response** header, not a request header!

Comment: `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` — You are making a **get** request, there is no content to describe the type of. You aren't posting JSON!

Comment: Agreed, you can't get around CORS restrictions by setting access-control headers in the request. Think about it logically - if it was so trivial to work around it then what would be the point of the restriction?? The client can't just arbitrarily decide it doesn't like CORS. The **server** must set those headers in its response to your request. If it doesn't set them, and it's not your server application, then there's probably nothing you can do (unless the server maintainer allows you  to register your app to be approved for making CORS request to that server)

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your `requestOptions` object initialization. You could provide an Object with type `{ [param: string]: string | string[]; }`.

```
const requestOptions = {
    headers: headerDict
};
```

or use the [HttpHeaders](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders) class instead of the `Headers`.